# Compile data from different models into one list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

My app has a user model, as well as multiple other date related models/tables such as anniversaries, holidays, birthdays, and and "other dates" custom model.

I have a user dashboard view that lists them all separately as shown below. How can i display all of these lists as one (call it upcoming events or something) that is listed chronologically and shows them upcoming dates for a certain period of time.

**View**

*note - These are displayed in a table/list but i stripped html for clarity

```
    <h1>Holidays</h1>
<% if @user.holidays.any? %>
  <% @user.holidays.each do |hld| %>
    <%= hld.name %>
    <%= hld.date %>
<% end %>

    <h1>Friends Birthdays</h1>
<% if @user.friends.any? %>
  <% @user.friends.each do |frd| %>
      <%= frd.name %>
      <%= frd.dob %>
  <% end %>


    <h1> Anniversary </h1>
<% if @user.anniversaries.any? %>
  <% @user.anniversaries.each do |ann| %>
      <%= ann.spouse_name %>
      <%= ann.anniversary_date %> 
   <% end %>
```

Thanks!

**Models**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :friends
 has_many :occasions
 has_many :user_holidays
 has_many :holidays, :through => :user_holidays
 has_many :anniversaries

class Holiday < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_holidays
  has_many :users, :through => :user_holidays    
end

class Friend < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end


class Anniversary < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to be efficient (you could just combine the arrays, sort them and be done with it), there is no direct way to do it through the relations. I am assuming you have an events model which has a foreign key to the user, in that case,

```
Events.where(:user_id => @user.id).where(<EVENT DATE FILTERS>).order("event_date DESC")
```

-- EDIT --

This is quite dirty, but I cant think of any other direct db way of accomplishing this.

```
events = @user.holidays.map{|h| [h.name, h.date, :holiday]} + \
         @user.friends.map{|f| [f.name, f.dob, :birthday]} + \
         @user.anniversaries.map{|a| [a.spouse_name, a.anniversary.date, :anniversary]}
events.map!{|event| {:name => event[0], :date => event[1], :event_type => event[2]}}
# You now have an array of hashes with the events name, date and type.

events.sort{|a, b| a[:date] <=> b[:date]}  # sort / filter
```

Comment: No events model.. All of the models (holidays, friends, anniversary ect) are independent of each other and related to the user... added models above